# How to delete Chinese characters in Lisp code (solved)

Tags: cut-copy-paste, comments, filetype-clojure, filetype-lisp

EDIT. The cause of the problem has been found: the problem only appears when Tamas Kovacs' Paredit plugin is enabled.

I have a lisp file containing comments and strings written using Chinese characters. The file is named `chinese.scm`:

```
;; 華文。
(display "一二三。")
```

I tried to delete a character using `x` in normal mode. Positioning my cursor on `文`, I pressed `x` once, but this is what I see on the screen:

```
;; 華<96><87>。
(display "一二三。")
```

Vim appears to be deleting a byte instead of the entire Chinese character. The same problem appears when I try to delete a character within the string above. This problem only appears with lisp files (i.e. Scheme, Common Lisp, Clojure), and not with non-code files.

Surprisingly, deleting the Chinese character here works perfectly:

```
(印 "Dire bonjour à la dame.")  ; After deletion: ( "Dire bonjour à la dame.")
```

Questions are:

1. Why does this happen?
2. How can this problem be fixed? i.e. How can I delete one Chinese character in comments and strings using `x`?

Comment: I would guess that Vim's `'encoding'` is set to something other than `utf-8`, so Vim is editing individual bytes instead of full Unicode characters. Usually that would result in garbage being shown, too. But somehow your terminal is able to correctly interpret the characters (as long as they're complete), maybe through a custom `'termencoding'` setting. I couldn't reproduce this, though.

Comment: @IngoKarkat That was what I suspected too, but the encoding I used is in fact `utf-8`.

Comment: @IngoKarkat I just discovered that this problem only appears when Tamas Kovacs' Paredit plugin is enabled. Thanks for looking into it.

Comment: could it be having the `delcombine` option set?

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt No. `set delcombine?` shows `nodelcombine`.

Comment: Glad you got this problem sorted out. Note that it's preferable to "accept" the answer that solves the problem (by clicking on that answer's checkmark/tick) rather than edit the title to include the text "solved".

Answer (score 2):

You mentioned you are using the [paredit plugin](https://github.com/vim-scripts/paredit.vim).

If you look into the plugin, you can see, that the <kbd>DEL</kbd> Key is mapped to the function [PareditEraseFwd](https://github.com/vim-scripts/paredit.vim/blob/791c3a0cc3155f424fba9409a9520eec241c189c/plugin/paredit.vim#L125).

This function will later call [s:EraseFw](https://github.com/vim-scripts/paredit.vim/blob/master/plugin/paredit.vim#L1030) and if you look closely into the definition you see that in your case it will do [this](https://github.com/vim-scripts/paredit.vim/blob/791c3a0cc3155f424fba9409a9520eec241c189c/plugin/paredit.vim#L1069-L1072):

```
    elseif pos < len(line) && pos >= a:startcol
        " Erasing a non-special character
        let reg = reg . line[pos]
        let line = strpart( line, 0, pos ) . strpart( line, pos+1 )
```

Note, the `strpart()` function works with byte indices, so it will just remove a single byte instead of a single letter.

You should most likely contact the maintainer of the plugin mentioned at the top of the file to have this fixed (one could for example use a combination of `split()` and `join()` using the `.` to get character indices). When you talk to the maintainer, you should probably also mention that it would be desirable to let the user configure, whether or not he wants certain keys to be mapped (so you could prevent the plugin from mapping the <kbd>DEL</kbd> key at all, unfortunately, this is not possible currently).

(Unrelated, to that, it looks like the plugin should be rather distributed as filetype specific plugin instead of a general purpose plugin. So this is something else to be considered by the maintainer of the plugin).

However for a quick solution, you could create a file ~/.vim/after/ftplugin/scheme.vim (create non existing directories) and add

```
" prevent errors, in case of del being not mapped
" a nicer solution would just check if the key is being mapped
" using `mapcheck("<del>", 'n')
:sil! unmap <buffer> <del>
```

Or you could disable the whole plugin by setting `:let g:paredit_mode=0` into your `.vimrc` file (which effectively disables the plugin completely. But then you could also just uninstall the plugin).

Also note, that the vim-scripts mirror on github is currently unmaintained and the latest version of the paredit plugin on [vim.org](https://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3998) is actually 0.9.13 while the github mirror only has the [0.9.12 version].

**Update**
Actually, it looks like version 0.9.13 fixes your problem. Quoting from the changes of the vim.org page (emphasized by myself):

> Always leave cursor to opening char's pos after wrapping selection.
>
> Fix possible cursor move problem caused by &indentexpr when using the
>   c operator.
>
> Bugfix: 2 keymaps assumed g:paredit_leader is identical to ','.
>
> Fix for paredit 'x' and 'X' when clipboard=unnamed.
>
> Added support for hy.
>
> Use  instead of mapleader.
>
> Enhanced detection of forms balanced state.
>
> Unescaped square brackets in balance detection.
>
> Bugfix: pressing  (for completion) followed by ')'.
>
> Remove invalid uses of `call`.
>
> **Fixed problem with 'x' and 'X' commands when erasing multi-byte unicode character.**
>
> Fix Paredit burfing (by moving parens left or right) when there are
>   stings as elements.
>
> Added paredit support for shen language.
>
> Do not skip parens after \ when searching for pairs.

Comment: I actually have the commit that claims to fix the problem, but the problem appears regardless. The fix appears to work only for some multibyte characters (e.g. infinity ∞), but not Chinese characters.

Comment: then please contact the maintainer. It's his responsibility to fix it. Actually using `norm! x` instead of lines 1123-1130 should fix it.